# Best way to get atomic / sql timestamp like functionality

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I need some functionality to move data to other systems and was wondering if there is some sort of atomic increment . I did see something like that for the reliable collection replication but it does not appear to be exposed.

Any ideas ?  I could build my own but having an entire collection for a single value and running transactions over both seems over kill .

I see transactionId but i assume this is not persisted across restarts ?